# My laptop doesn't recognize my phone after enabling developer options on my phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning android studio and I enabled developer options on my phone to connect it to my laptop, but after that my laptop doesn't recognize my phone anymore.
My laptop is windows 10 asus and my phone is android 10 Nokia 9 pureview.
I almost did what I could found about it on the Internet.

Comment: What do you mean by "my laptop doesn't recognize my phone any more"? What happens when you plug in your phone to your laptop? What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: possible solutions:
1. make sure the usb cable you are using is working AND supports data transfering (some of the ceheaper chargers will only charge but won't let you transfer files between devices)
2. try running "killall adb" pr "adb kill-server" and then "adb start-server" command
3. Try Swapping USB ports and cables
4. Check whether "USB debugging" is enabled

Comment: do you mean android studio doesn't recognize the device?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. My laptop just charge the phone and didn't recognize it. There is an error on recognizing.

Comment: I checked these solutions and didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your hardware??

the cable

the charging port

try testing your phone on other laptops

or test your laptop with other phones

Comment: Yes I checked it and other PCs had no problem recognizing my phone with the cable.